# The difference between congruence and equivalence class?

Tags: relations, congruences

I've got an excercise solved by my teacher, it says I've got to prove a relation $R$ of elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a **congruence**. In the solved exercise he just proved Reflexivity, transitivity and symetry of $R$. Is this enough? As far as I know that proves only it is a relation of equivalence. Is he missing something?

EDITED from [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818872/the-difference-between-congruence-and-equivalence-class#comment3716874_1818872):  It says "Prove $R$ is a congruence **with respect to the sum of pairs**" btw $(a,b)R(c,d) \Leftrightarrow 3(a−c)+2(b−d)=0$.

Comment: It's the same difference between a theorem and a lemma, and a proposition. Although in some contexts "congruence" might have a stronger meaning, this does not seem like such context.

Comment: It says "Prove R is a congruence **with respect to the sum of pairs**" btw $(a,b)R(b,c) \iff 3(a-c)+2(b-d)=0$

Comment: Probably you mean $(a, b)R(c, d)$, rather than $(a, b)R(b, c)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is "congruence" really used synonymously with "equivalence relation"? That's such a bad convention . . .

Comment: yes i did mean that, thank you for edit. gl

Answer (score 6):

An **equivalence relation** is just a relation which is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric.

A **congruence relation**, however, is a bit more: it's a relation which *respects some structure*. Note that this means the phrase "congruence relation" by itself is vague: I have to tell you *what structure I want it to respect*.

Here's the standard picture. I have some structure $\mathcal{X}$, which in this case means a set $X$ equipped with a specific "operation of interest" $f$ on $X$. A *congruence on $\mathcal{X}$* is then an equivalence relation $E$ which respects this operation, in the sense that $$x_1Ey_1, x_2Ey_2, . . ., x_nEy_n\implies f(x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n)Ef(y_1, y_2, . . . , y_n).$$ For example, let $X=\mathbb{N}$, and consider the operation $+$. Then the relation $E$ given by $xEy\iff [{x\over 2}]=[{y\over 2}]$ (where $[\cdot]$ is the floor operation) is an equivalence relation, but *not* a congruence: since $1E0$ but $1+1$ is *not* $E$-related to $0+0$.

(And we can similarly define the notion of congruence for sets equipped with multiple operations, or operations and relations, or various further generalizations.)

---

So in your context, you have a set $X$ - the set of all pairs of reals - and an operation on $X$ - described in your comment to Asaf. You need to show that the equivalence relation given respects that operation - that is, $$\mbox{$(a, b)R(a', b')$ and $(c, d)R(c', d')$ implies $(a, b)+(c, d)R(a', b')+(c', d')$}.$$ If your teacher indeed only proved reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity, then they gave an incomplete solution; however, showing that it's a congruence isn't too hard.